# Ubuntu 16.04 OpenFOAM-5.0 makeParaView Qt5 Error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, qt5

I'm trying to build and install fluid simulation software OpenFOAM from source. The first step is building all the third party software by running `./Allwmake` in the `$WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR`. I did this, with no errors, and proceeded to build and install ParaView by running `./makeParaView`. This leads to the following error (beginning is clipped for your, and my own, sanity):

...

```
-- Looking for jbg_newlen
-- Looking for jbg_newlen - not found
-- Protobuf: doing try-compiles for hash map/set headers
-- Protobuf: doing try-compiles for pthread test
CMake Error at CMake/ParaViewQt.cmake:65 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt5" that is compatible
  with requested version "5.6".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.5.1
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.5.1

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Qt/Widgets/CMakeLists.txt:203 (pv_find_package_qt)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-5.0/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.4.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-5.0/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.4.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".`
```

I have tried the solution found [here](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2017-January/039069.html), but I still get the same error. It should be said that I did install Qt5.6.x into my home directory and altered the paths suggested by the link accordingly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be helpful to be specific about exactly what you did, and **how** you altered the paths

Comment: Do you know you can easily install it from repository? https://openfoam.org/download/5-0-ubuntu/

Comment: steeldriver -- So I didn't really 'alter' any paths, I guess that was a poor choice of words. But, since I installed Qt5.6.x to $HOME, I changed the path listed in the link (`-DQt5_DIR=/software/path/qt-5.7.1/lib/cmake/Qt5`) to `-DQt5_DIR=/home/trent/Qt5.6.x/lib/cmake/Qt5` (where the "x" in "Qt5.6.x" was I believe 3, but I can't recall for certain).

Comment: Vitor -- Yes I know about the repo and how easy the installation is as I was going to install that in the first place; but, because I want to see the source and possibly make some changes and experimentations (I hope to help with the dev eventually), I need to compile from the source.

Comment: @Trent I am trying to understand **where** you did that, since AFAIK the `-D` here refers to a `cmake` command-line option - whereas you appear to be running a provided script `./Allwmake` rather than executing `cmake` directly

Comment: @Trent I dont know your skills on openfoam, but it is possible to create and edit solvers and libraries even with the dev installation. That is what researchers usually do. Good lucky.

Comment: @Vitor Abella You are absolutely right, the packaged versions come with all the sources you need for compiling any custom application that involves whichever extent of OpenFOAM's code base. However it does not ship with the make scripts you need for recompiling the code - which might make sense performance wise in case you run a system with some custom MPI, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you confused the name of the environment variable, `Qt5_DIR`, with an option accepted by `cmake` to set the Qt5 directory: `cmake -DQt5_DIR="....."`. Bear in mind that when you call `./makeParaView`, it will run in its own environment and won't see any variables you declared locally. To make your Qt5 installation available to the script and also to all processes it calls you need to export it:

```
export Qt5_DIR="/home/trent/Qt5.6.x/lib/cmake/Qt5"
```

Do make sure to doublecheck the path you specify is correct and actually contains the requested `Qt5Config.cmake`.

I am not entirely sure if this solution will also make the linker aware of where the Qt libraries can be found, so you might as well communicate that by adding the respective directory to the path for shared libraries:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/trent/Qt5.6.x/lib":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Comment: According to the ./makeParaView documentation, I should be able to pass cmake options for the build, not sure why it didn't work... Nevertheless, this solution worked fantastically, thanks a ton!