# Protocol Buffer runtime Library Error

Tags: 16.04, command-line, libraries

I'm using fluid simulation software called OpenFOAM (v5.0), which uses ParaView 5.4.0. I'm receiving an error regarding libprotobuf (see below). I suspect that it may have something to do with a previous version of OpenFOAM that was installed, but I'm not sure exactly what to change.

Error produced by running `paraFOAM` in a simulation case directory
Full context:

```
trent@Tars:~/OpenFOAM/trent-5.0/run/channelCoarse$ paraFoam
Created temporary 'channelCoarse.OpenFOAM'
libprotobuf FATAL /home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-5.0/ParaView-5.4.0/ThirdParty/
protobuf/vtkprotobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:62] This program requires
version 2.6.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is
2.3.0.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make
sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-
time library.  (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-ui6vjS/mir-0.26.3+16.04
.20170605/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This leads me to believe that I need to update my libprotobuf; however, here is the output of `dpkg -l | grep libprotobuf`:

```
ii  libprotobuf-java              2.6.1-1.3     all       Java bindings for protocol buffers
ii  libprotobuf-lite9v5:amd64     2.6.1-1.3     amd64     protocol buffers C++ library (lite version)
ii  libprotobuf9v5:amd64          2.6.1-1.3     amd64     protocol buffers C++ library
```

And here, for good measure, is the output of `locate libprotobuf`:

```
/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-4.1/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.0.1/lib/libprotobuf-lite.so
/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-4.1/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.0.1/lib/libprotobuf.so
/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-4.1/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.0.1/lib/paraview-5.0/libprotobuf-lite.so
/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-4.1/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.0.1/lib/paraview-5.0/libprotobuf.so
/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-5.0/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.4.0/lib/libprotobuf-lite.so
/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-5.0/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.4.0/lib/libprotobuf.so
/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-5.0/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.4.0/lib/paraview-5.4/libprotobuf-lite.so
/home/trent/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-5.0/platforms/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.4.0/lib/paraview-5.4/libprotobuf.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9.0.1
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libprotobuf.so.8
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libprotobuf.so.8.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-java
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-lite9v5
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf9v5
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-java/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-java/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-lite9v5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-lite9v5/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf9v5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf9v5/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf-java.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf-java.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf-lite9v5:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf-lite9v5:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf-lite9v5:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf-lite9v5:amd64.triggers
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf9v5:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf9v5:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf9v5:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libprotobuf9v5:amd64.triggers
```

A few notes: I was installing from source and having Qt5-related building issues earlier, but those were solved implementing steps which can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941697/ubuntu-16-04-openfoam-5-0-makeparaview-qt5-error). Earlier today I made these changes permanent by adding the exported variables to a file in my /etc/profile.d directory. Additionally, though I doubt it has any relation to this issue, I replaced the qmake symbolic link in my /usr/bin/ directory (which linked to /usr/bin/qtchooser/) with one that links to my Qt5.6 directory in $HOME.

Hope you can help, thanks!