# Ubuntu 16.04 OpenFOAM-v1706 ParaView Installation Error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, qt, qt5

I'm trying to build and install OpenFOAM-v1706+ from the source for Linux provided [here](http://openfoam.com/download/install-source.php). I'm following the build guide provided [here](http://openfoam.com/code/build-guide.php), but I am having issues with an error that occurs when I try to compile ParaView with the following commands:

```
cd $WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR
./makeParaView
```

The installation fails with the following message (I've clipped everything before the error...)

```
CMake Error at CMake/ParaViewQt.cmake:65 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt5" that is 
compatible with requested version "5.6".

The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.5.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.5.1

Call Stack (most recent call first):
Qt/Widgets/CMakeLists.txt:203 (pv_find_package_qt)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fdrc/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-
v1706/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.4.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/fdrc/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-
v1706/build/linux64Gcc/ParaView-5.4.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I checked my Qt5 build with Qt creator, and the newest installation is Qt 5.6.1 (not Qt 5.5.1), but the path to Qt 5.6.1 is different. The path to Qt 5.6.1 is

```
/home/fdrc/Qt5.6.1/5.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

whereas the path to Qt 5.5.1 is

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
```

I suspect that this is related to my issue, but I am not sure. I had tried to solve my problem following a similar solution that was posted [here on this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941697/ubuntu-16-04-openfoam-5-0-makeparaview-qt5-error), but upon trying to compile ParaView I received the same error as above. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the build guide from your second link and attempted to build ParaView. The build appeared to go through without any problems.

Looking at the error you have detailed and after following the guide myself, it may be possible you have not followed the OpenFOAM system requirements page [here](http://openfoam.com/documentation/system-requirements.php). This is the first step in the build guide.

This page provides 3 lines to install dependencies for a Ubuntu system. I'm not sure if you have executed these but I think it's possible you may have at least missed the second line which is:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev freeglut3-dev libqtwebkit-dev
```

This line is installing the required Qt4 development libraries and the system requirements link states at the top `Qt: 4.7.2 (optional - required for ParaView build)`.

Therefore, it would suggest that ParaView requires Qt4 and not Qt5. It may be possible that ParaView can be built using Qt5, however I'm not sure of this. I would recommend following the build instructions and use Qt4 as it did work when I tried it.

Comment: You are right, I did not follow the system requirements in installing Qt5 - I had overlooked that. I uninstalled Qt5 and used `export QT_SELECT=qt4` before `./makeParaView`, and I was able to install ParaView with no problems. Thank you very much for the help!